# Regular Expression to validate username with a symbol prefix

Tags: java, android, regex

**Requirements:** I need to put an `InputFilter` on an `EditText` which is accepting a field with certain limitations:

1. should Only accept `[a-zA-Z0-9._]`
2. `@` can or can not be first character (I need to append @ as prefix to the name)
3. can only start with alphanumeric `[a-zA-Z0-9]` not with `[._]`

Currently i am using :

```
String regEx="[@]?(([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1})?)+[a-zA-Z0-9._]*";
```

But it is accepting `[._]` to be the first character.

Can anyone help me on this?

Sample:
Input :- Mack --> Then `onTextChange` i am adding `@` as prefix which should not be mandatory -> @Mack

Now when i delete char one by from editText on each text deletion remaining value should pass the RegEx. 
With Wiktor Stribiżew suggestion i am not able to detete after `@M` .

Comment: Try `@?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*`, you may check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/0kFYVK/1).

Comment: People downvote so quickly here. @WiktorStribiżew Tried that too . But its not letting me delete the last char from edittext . Seems like first part is mandatory . But its not for me i want to delete text from editText .

Comment: I think I got it now - `@?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*)?`

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew i have added some sample . I tried my best .

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53630416/3832970) with the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0kFYVK/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1})?` part in your pattern matches an *optional* alphanumeric char (1 or 0 occurrences) 1 or 0 times. It means it can match an empty string.

The point here is to match an optional `@` first, then use an optional sequence of patterns: an alphanumeric char followed with 0+ alphanumeric chars, `.` or `_`:

```
@?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*)?
```

Since the whole input must be matched, no need using `^` and `$` anchors.

**Details**

- `@?` - an optional `@`
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a sequence of patterns:

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric char
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9._]*` - 0 or more alphanumeric chars, `.` or `_`.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/0kFYVK/2).

Comment: `TransPerfect` .. A bundle of thanks for detailed explanation . This is exactly what i need . Damm!!! I have respect of `RegEx` Gold Bedgers .

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you :

```
String regEx="@?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._]*)?"
```

Comment: Oh I see your updates, I corrected my answer too :) @Diazdiaz